# Web API POST using [FromBody] giving null

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Here is my WebAPI (c#):

```
 [Route("")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void SaveTestRun([FromBody] object data)
        {
            inputResultsToDatabase(data);
        }
```

Here is my ajax request:

```
sendTestData() {
        this.get('ajax').request('/web/api/test/', {
            data: {"name":"John Doe", "age":18, "country":"United States of America"},
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'object',
            headers: {
                AjaxRequestUniqueKey: getAntiForgeryToken()
            }
        });
    },
```

I Get the object to show up in google developer tools, but 'data' is set to null. I've tried sending object as a string, with the same results.

Comment: try converting the object to json first, delete dataType, and set contentType to application/json

Answer (score 0):

[FromBody] is used to extract simple types from request body.

Update your Action to accept a typed parameter

```
public class MyObject {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
public void SaveTestRun(MyObject data) {
    inputResultsToDatabase(data);
}
```

Next make sure that your are posting the data in the correct format

```
sendTestData() {
    var data = {"name":"John Doe", "age":18, "country":"United States of America"};
    this.get('ajax').request('/web/api/test/', {
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            AjaxRequestUniqueKey: getAntiForgeryToken()
        }
    });
},
```